# Have an IIS site with a sub-directory on another hard drive

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8

I have a site where users upload audio files they've recorded. The primary hard drive the site is running on is fairly small, so I'd like to make the upload directory reside on a separate, larger hard drive. I could create another site running under a subdomain, but I'd prefer to keep the URL structure like: site.com/uploads instead of uploads.site.com. Is it possible to point /uploads do a different folder/drive than the rest of the site is running on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you just create a Virtual Directory off of `site.com`.  You can give it a path on a local physical drive or an UNC path to a remote resource (assuming you have the appropriate permissions).

In IIS Manager:

- Right-click the site.com site and choose Add Virtual Directory...
- In the Alias box enter `uploads`
- In the Physical Path box enter the path to your uploads folder